# What does "in space" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The earth is already in space.

Does "in space" here mean that there is still plenty of room in earth?

Comment: Can you provide more context?  It sounds like this is referring to [outer space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_space), but it's hard to tell without more context.

Comment: I bet it's a 'hip-hop' or 'rap' song called [B.I.B.L.E](https://genius.com/Killah-priest-bible-lyrics) by someone calling themselves 'Killah Priest', and I _think_ he is putting forward the notion that you don't have to believe the promises of priests and follow, churches so that you will one day 'go to heaven' (i.e. in space, the sky, 'up above', etc) because you are already there (because the earth exists in space, as do the Moon, Mars, the stars, etc) "Why should you die to go to Heaven?".

Answer (score 2):

It means that the earth already exists in the cosmos; that we who are on the earth are already "in space" in the same way that an astronaut in a space ship is "in space" when floating outside the earth's atmosphere. It would mean that the earth is like a space ship.

*In* is a preposition which tells us that **space** (the *direct object*) contains **the earth** (the *subject*). Space in earth means that *the earth* contains *space*, because in that sentence, the earth is now the direct object, and space is the subject. Using "Is...in" is another way of saying "contains":

> The Earth contains space = space is in the earth (or the earth *has* space)

versus

> Space contains the earth = the earth is in space

Note that these are two [different meanings of *space*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/space).